# How To create multiple function in Adapter Class Android with Retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, adapter

I have an adapter, thats keep all data that i needed, but i want to use the adapter in two class. One to show data in recylerview,and other to show just the image of data in ViewFlipper. But i can't realize how to make a multiple function on my adapter to use it in another class(flipper).

I'll show the code so far, for the adapter

```
public class AdapterCafe extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCafe.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<CafeItem> cafe;
public AdapterCafe(Context context, List<CafeItem> data_cafe) {

    this.context = context;
    this.cafe = data_cafe;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cafe_card, parent, false);
    View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filppers_item, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    MyViewHolder holder2 = new MyViewHolder(view2);
    holder2.tvNamacafeFlip.setText(cafe.get(viewType).getNamaCafe());
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // Set widget
    holder.tvNama.setText(cafe.get(position).getNamaCafe());
    holder.tvAlamat.setText(cafe.get(position).getAlamatCafe());

    final String urlGambarCafe = "http://192.168.43.159/web/ngafeapp/" + cafe.get(position).getFotoCafe();

    Picasso.with(context).load(urlGambarCafe).into(holder.ivGambar);
    Picasso.with(context).load(urlGambarCafe).into(holder.ivgambarFlip);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Mulai activity Detail
            Intent varIntent = new Intent(context, cafedetailActivity.class);
            // sisipkan data ke intent
            varIntent.putExtra("ID_CAFE",cafe.get(position).getIdCafe());
            varIntent.putExtra("NAMA_CAFE", cafe.get(position).getNamaCafe());
            varIntent.putExtra("WKT_CAFE", cafe.get(position).getJamOperasionalWeekDay());
            varIntent.putExtra("WKT_CAFE2", cafe.get(position).getJamOperasionalWeekEnd());
            varIntent.putExtra("ALAMAT_CAFE", cafe.get(position).getAlamatCafe());
            varIntent.putExtra("FOTO_CAFE", urlGambarCafe);
            varIntent.putExtra("NO_TELEPON",cafe.get(position).getNoTelepon());
            varIntent.putExtra("DESKRIPSI", cafe.get(position).getDeskripsiCafe());
            varIntent.putExtra("LATITUDE",cafe.get(position).getLatitude());
            varIntent.putExtra("LONGITUDE",cafe.get(position).getLongitude());

            context.startActivity(varIntent);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cafe.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivGambar, ivgambarFlip;
    TextView tvNama, tvAlamat,tvNamacafeFlip;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivGambar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.images_cafe);
        tvNama = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_cafe);
        tvAlamat= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alamatcafe);
    }
}
```

}

So, i try to make the othe View, but it can't works . Can you help me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to define your adapter as an `abstract class` and make two separate class that you want to have for those two places.

I guess you want to have two different `onCreateViewHolder` functions.

- AdapterCafe

```
public abstract class AdapterCafe extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCafe.MyViewHolder> {
 // Add every thing that are not different for the two cases.
 // Anything except `onCreateViewHolder`
}
```

- Case1Adapter

```
class Case1Adapter extends AdapterCafe {

 // Now override `onCreateViewHolder`
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cafe_card, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    holder.tvNamacafeFlip.setText(cafe.get(viewType).getNamaCafe());
    return holder;
}
```

- Case2Adapter

```
class Case2Adapter extends AdapterCafe {

 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filppers_item, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder2 = new MyViewHolder(view2);
    holder2.tvNamacafeFlip.setText(cafe.get(viewType).getNamaCafe());
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: so i need to make the two separate(Case1,Case2) class in Adapter cafe?

Comment: Yes. But this isn't actually two classes. You are putting common code in one class and thise two classes will use the common code and each will have it's own different code. You know what I mean?